# Softlayer Security Software Access Protection Logs

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After ordering security software (McAFee Anti-virus), how to get anti-virus log and Access Protection Logs using API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This information may help you:

https://forums.softlayer.com/forum/softlayer-developer-network/implementations/83143-python-api-retrieve-the-view-access-protection-logs

https://forums.softlayer.com/forum/softlayer-developer-network/implementations/83114-get-mcafee-epolicy-orchestrator-version45-event

Currently the information that you want to display is available only using SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v3="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <authenticate xsi:type="v3:authenticate">
         <username xsi:type="xsd:string">?</username>
         <apiKey xsi:type="xsd:string">?</apiKey>
      </authenticate>
      <SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareInitParameters xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareInitParameters">
         <id xsi:type="xsd:int">9510000</id>
      </SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareInitParameters>
      <SoftLayer_ObjectMask xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_ObjectMask">
         <mask xsi:type="xsd:string">?</mask>
      </SoftLayer_ObjectMask>
      <SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareObjectFilter xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareObjectFilter"/>
      <SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareObjectMask xsi:type="v3:SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareObjectMask">
               <mask>
                 <latestAntivirusEvents>
                   <virusActionTaken/>
                </latestAntivirusEvents>            
               </mask>
      </SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpywareObjectMask>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v3:getObject soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is an issue related to this problem.

Comment: thanks, in softlayer control, security software list (json data) include epoVersion value. how can i get that information use masking ?

Comment: i was tested it use SL API Explorer but there was no data response {
    "hardwareId": null,
    "id": 9225279,
    "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "06B714F6C082",
    "epoVersion": "4.5",
    "latestAccessProtectionEvents": [],
    "latestAntivirusEvents": [],
    "latestSpywareEvents": []
}

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem.I tested the request without data. I'm trying to isolate the problem. I'll let you know any news. My apologies.

Comment: There is an issue reported related to this problem. To get the wanted information we need to use SOAP requests. The answer was updated with  a SOAP request example. I hope it can help you. **Reference:** [api-retrieve-the-view-access-protection-logs](https://forums.softlayer.com/forum/softlayer-developer-network/implementations/83143-python-api-retrieve-the-view-access-protection-logs)